# Randomly no access from local SSMS to EC2 with SQL Server behind ELB AWS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, ssms, amazon-elb

I've recently created two EC2 and I installed SQL Server on each of them. These two machines composed a Failover cluster with "Always On" functionality on.

On another EC2 I have different websites that access database through the "Always On" listener.

Until here, everything went as planned.

My problem is that I wanted to access the database from my local SSMS. I'm on a different domain from my VPC where the databases are.

To resolve this problem I've created a Network Load Balancer on AWS and added a DNS on Route53 (and managed security group, ...).

Since one week I have access to my databases from my local SSMS but sometimes I'm losing connection to it and by doing nothing after few minutes it's coming back. I have this issue only from my SSMS, at the same time all the websites accessing directly the "Always On" listener don't have issues. That's why I think my problem is related to the Load Balancer but I really have no clue how to correct it.

Do you think I should have done differently and shouldn't have used a network load balancer here ?

Does the load balancer randomly drop queries or what might be the problem with it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This architecture is working well in fact. I'm not sure if it's the best one but I can do what I planned.

By simplifying all the process we found that the problem is coming from the VPN between our office and AWS. Our sysadmin is searching on it.

Thank you and I hope it could help others.